# Similarity Between Two Nilpotent Matrices

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

I am curious. Let's say we are given two $n \times n$ matrices $G$ and $F$ where both $G$ and $F$ are nilpotent matrices of order $k$, i.e., $G^{k-1} \neq O$ and $F^{k-1} \neq O$, but $G^{k} =O$ and $F^{k} = O$ (where $O = [o_{ij}]$. Would $G \sim F$?

I don't think so. I have the examples

\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0& 1\\0 & 0& 1\\0 & 0& 0\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -3& 2\\
15 & -9& 6\\
10 & -6& 4\\
\end{bmatrix}

Both matrices square to zero. I couldn't find a invertible transformation $T$ such that $T^{-1}GT = F$, so I want to safely assume they are not similar.Thus I want to conclude that nilpotent matrices of the same other aren't necessarily similar.

---

Sorry for the rather short post. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Presumably the order and the number of rows/columns are not the same $n$ here.

Comment: Yes, the order and the number of rows/columns are not the same $n$. I should have used $k$ instead. Sorry about the confusion. I shall change it.

Answer (score 3):

In your example (and in fact any $3 \times 3$ example with order $2$), both have Jordan canonical form

$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$
so they are in fact similar.  But in general, the answer is no.
Consider 
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr}\ \text{and}\ 
 \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$